# How to use amazon firefly in non Fire phone ( for example samsung mobile phones)

Tags: android, amazon-firefly

currently I'm developing an app for android that will be work on Samsung and HTC mobile phones, I need to use firefly sdk in my app, all articles I found talk about how to use it to develop an app for fire phone,
Is any one know a way to use the firefly sdk and make it work on non fire phones mobiles ?